How do I check if my websocket connection is broken with winhttp?
For the important context:

I'm trying to make a C++ client that connects and sends data to a websocket server. I didn't make and have no control over the server, its my friends. We have to use websockets because we're trying to connect to CC: Tweaked (a minecraft mod) computers.
I struggled to even make a valid websocket connection for a while, but my friend came in clutch with a solution (though I'm pretty sure he got help from AI). I've tried to do my own research on winhttp to understand it, and I don't think there are any major flaws in the code, but I'm not 100% sure (I did modify it a bit).

Currently my connection doesn't seem to sever even if the server is completely terminated. The program has no idea the connection is broken, and keeps trying to send data when I ask it to. How can I find out when the connection is broken so I can display it and disable sending data until it's reconnected?
Here are pastebin links to the class: WebSocketClient.cpp and WebSocketClient.h
I then have a different class for utilizing this client (in a wxWidgets program). For example, here's the function I use to send data:
json Client::Chat(std::string guid, std::string label, std::string data) {
    json message = {
        {"id", guid},
        {"label", label},
        {"data", data}
    };

    if (client.Send(message)) {
        std::string response = client.Receive();

        try {
            json responseJson = json::parse(response);
            return responseJson;
        }
        catch (json::parse_error& e) {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

I would like this function to know if the connection is active, because currently if the server shuts down and I call this function, my program will completely freeze waiting for a response that cannot come, until I forcibly shut it down.
After googling a bit I found something called the "keepalive concept". I'm not sure I understood it correctly, so maybe it's actually what I want, but after looking into it for a bit I'm pretty sure it won't help me. I don't want to keep the connection alive, I actively want to fully terminate it until a new one is made. At least that's what I think I want, but my networking knowledge is pretty lacking, so maybe I'm wrong on a more fundamental level.

Normally the call to those functions would fail when the socket is closed, and the return would express this error. Are you calling this code in a loop and not handling the failure case ?

You receive function isn't designed to fail, you would get ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION if you call WinHttpWebSocketReceive, but you don't handle it and just return an empty string, which you aren't even checking .... you need to start adding more error checking for that case, same for your send function.

@AhmedAEK I think I understand, but also I don't.
Regardless of whether it's good practice or not, I don't see how returning a default value if there's an error would cause my program to freeze.
I don't believe anything is looping this code, but as mentioned I am using wxWidgets and idk how all that works under the hood.
Lastly, although it doesn't seem relevant to my question, I would like to handle the error cases better since it probably is just good practice. How can I do this? The documentation doesn't seem to tell me, the basic examples doesn't handle anything.

Well, we cannot help you without seeing your code on the WxWidgets side, the code above will return nullptr on error and hand it back to whoever called it, we don't know what will happen then, i would assume you should then stop trying to read more input and establish a periodic task every few seconds to try to re-establish the connection, and not just fail silently and be stuck in a loop.

@AhmedAEK I didn't include it because nothing special happens.
It just calls the recieve function that is in the class I shared, which returns a normal std::string. Nothing special at all. What happens to that string after is irrelevant, no? I'm not calling recieve in a loop, just once on a button press. I've yet to even try what happens if the button is spammed, but I'm sure I'll have to implement a failsafe for that later.
